# Plotting level curves for 2-variable exponential equation (Lotka-Volterra) - how?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have

$$\frac{e^{(d x + b y)}}{x^c y^a}$$

Incidentally, this is the energy integral for [Lotka-Volterra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations) as given by my lecturer's notes.

I would like to draw the level curves for this equation for given $a,b,c,d$, so I am first solving the equation

$$\frac{e^{(d x + b y)}}{x^c y^a} = C$$

for some $C$, with the intention of later doing a `ContourPlot` on the result.

However, I have no luck with either `Solve` or `NSolve`.

```
F[x, y] = E^(d x + b y)/(x^c y^a)
F[x, y] /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1}
NSolve[(F[x, y] /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1}) == 1]
NSolve[(F[x, y] /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1}) > 1]
NSolve[(F[x, y] /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1}) == E^2]
NSolve[(F[x, y] /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1}) > E^2]
```

(I think the latter one *does* have at least the trivial solution, $$x,y=1$$).

However, this results in

```
NSolve[E^(x + y)/(x y) == 1]
NSolve::nsmet: "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve

NSolve[E^(x + y)/(x y) > 1]
NSolve::nsmet: "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve

NSolve[E^(x + y)/(x y) == E^2]
NSolve::nsmet: "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve

NSolve[E^(x + y)/(x y) > E^2]
NSolve::nsmet: "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve
```

Why, and how do I fix this?

I also tried plotting the function directly, for example

```
ContourPlot[
Evaluate[
  E^(d x + b y)/(x^c y^a) /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1}] < E,
{x, 0, 10},
{y, 0, 10}
],
```

or

```
ContourPlot[
Evaluate[
  E^(d x + b y)/(x^c y^a) /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1}] == E,
{x, 0, 10},
{y, 0, 10}
],
```

This gives me an empty plot, though. Again, why?

Comment: I believe you are missing an argument when using `NSolve`. Typing it like this: `Solve[E^(x + y)/(x y) == 1, x, InverseFunctions -> True]` yields `{{x -> -ProductLog[-(E^y/y)]}}`

Comment: In your second equation, the $c$ on the left is the same as the $c$ on the right?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis, no, sorry, my bad. It's just "some constant".

Comment: @Julian: How would I plot that, though, since it contains an $y$ on the right hand side?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's concentrate on case `{a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1}`

```
f[x_, y_] := (E^(d x + b y)/(x^c y^a) /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, 
    d -> 1});
```

I think `f[x,y]==E^2` gives you a single point `{1,1}`, while `f[x,y]==E^2+A` gives you a trajectory "around" `{1,1}` if `A` is positive and no real solutions if `A` is negative.
So your `f[x,y]==E` gives you empty plot. I don't think you can put inequalities in `ContourPlot`.

```
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[(f[x, y] == E^2 + #) & /@ {0.1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 20, 
    30}], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]
```

Gives you nice trajectories.

[image]

If you really want to use `NSolve` you can trick Mathematica and perform `NSolve[f[y, x] == C` for some particular `C` by plugging different `y` in it.
That will give you a pair `{x0,y0}` that makes `f[y0, x0] == C` true.

Let's do that for `C=E^2 + 30` - the outer curve. We will find two roots for `Y` in `Range[0.2, 3.8, 0.2]`.

```
dots = AppendTo[x /. NSolve[f[#, x] == E^2 + 30, x, Reals], #] & /@ 
   Range[0.2, 3.8, 0.2];
points = Flatten[#, 1] &@({{#[[1]], #[[3]]}, {#[[2]], #[[3]]}} & /@ 
     dots);
cp = ContourPlot[
   Evaluate[(f[x, y] == E^2 + #) & /@ {0.1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 20, 
      30}], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, GridLines -> Automatic];
Show[cp, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[points]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: You, sir, are full of awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Try with the package CurvesGraphics6 (for more details see [Gianluca Gorni](https://users.dimi.uniud.it/%7Egianluca.gorni/Mma/Mma.html)):

The function $V(x,y)$:

```
V[x_, y_] := Exp[d x + b y]/(x^c y^a) /. {a -> 18/10, b -> 9/10, c -> 81/100, d -> 54/100}
```

The ColorFunction:

```
CoolColor[ z_ ] := RGBColor[z, 1 - z, 1];
```

The level curves:

```
LevelPlot3D[V[x, y], {x, 0.5, 3}, {y, 0.9, 4}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, BoxStyle -> Directive[Black, 
DotDashed], PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.03]}, ColorFunction -> CoolColor, 
ShowProjectedLevelSets -> True, ProjectAt -> -2, LabelStyle -> 
Directive[Black, Small], Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3}, Automatic, None}, 
TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Thick]]
```

[image]